# AWS EC2 AMI and RDS Snapshot sharing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, amazon-rds

We are currently migrating our AWS infrastructure into another AWS Account,

To do so, I created AMIs of my EC2 instances which I need to redeploy in the newer AWS account,
Similarly I took Snapshot of the RDS which I will be needing.

I shared the AMIs and the RDS with the new AWS Account Number.

What I am worried about is,
**When the old account is cleaned and shut down,

will my shared AMIs and Snapshots get removed from the new account as well?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will go away and be inaccessible from the new account, since they will no longer exist.

Sharing only gives the remote account *permission* to access the resource. It doesn't copy or clone them.

From the new account, you need to make a copy of the shared [AMIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/CopyingAMIs.html) and shared [DB Snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html) if you want them to be permanently available.

Comment: If I've created an EC2 and RDS from the shared copies, will the running instances in the new account get terminated too?

Comment: The instances will not be terminated.  But note, for clarity, shared images aren't "shared copies."  Access to the originals is shared.